# How to change the tick length of 3D plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

A test code is in the following. When I add the length=10, the tick length does not change at all. Anyone can help?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.scatter((0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0))
ax.w_xaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_yaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.w_zaxis.line.set_color('red')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.zaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')   
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')  
ax.tick_params(axis='z', colors='red')  # add length = 10 does not change the length of ticks, why?

plt.show()
```

Comment: [From the current documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html?highlight=3d%20quiver%20plot#module-mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d): "Axes3D currently ignores some of these settings." Remember, matplotlib was designed as a 2D library, the 3D functionality was added later.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you! Any other package that you recommend to use for the better control of plotting 3D plot?

Comment: If you need more than basic 3D plotting functionality - matplotlib recommends [MayaVi](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html). I have no idea what this recommendation is based on - for my needs, mplot3d is sufficient.